# SQL between query issue

Tags: sql, between

I have 2 tables.
One with addresses (separately name and house number), and other with Regions where there are Street number and fields from and to. E.g. Region Europe is everything that belongs in street Europe street from 1 upto 200 street number.
I need join where each address falls in to appropriate region. However cevat is that house numbers can be also 120a, 120b, 120c and so on. I fail to achieve this with simple "between" and my number 120a falls into wrong range.

It is MS SQL Server lite

```
Table 1
1st street | 22
1st street | 22a
1st street | 24
1st street | 33
1st street | 112a




Table2
Region 1 | 1st street | 1 | 30
Region 2 | 1st street | 31 | 40
Region 3 | 1st street | 41 | 200
```

So I would like to merge them to get result for example 1st street 22, 22a, 24 belongs to Region 1 since street numbers are between 1 and 30.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please edit your question to provide sample data, the desired output, and the query you've tried so far that isn't working. Also, please add the tag for the database you're using, because syntax and functionality varies between different RDBMSs. Thanks. :)

Comment: Can you write a sqlLite UDF?   I think if you write a UDF to convert the 22a,112a,etc. to integers, and then use that function, would be the safest bet, although it would likely impact performance a bit...

Answer (score 1):

First you have to convert the housenr with extension to just the house number.  You could use `patindex` to search for the first non-numeric character.  If none is found, use the entire string. Otherwise use the start of the string up to the first non-numeric character.

```
cast(case 
when patindex('%[^0-9]%', housenrext) = 0 then housenrext
else substring(housenrext, 1, patindex('%[^0-9]%', housenrext) - 1)
end as int) as housenr
```

With the above construct in a subquery, you can `join` to the region table to find the matching region:

```
select  *
from    (
        select  cast(case 
                when patindex('%[^0-9]%', housenrext) = 0 then housenrext
                else substring(housenrext, 1, patindex('%[^0-9]%', housenrext) - 1)
                end as int) as housenr
        ,       street
        from    @address
        ) as addr
left join
        @region region
on      addr.street = region.street
        and addr.housenr between region.startnr and region.endnr
```

[Full example at SE Data.](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/120911/)

Comment: Andomar got it right.  I was forgetting that house #112 would NOT be between 10 and 20.  I've voted to delete my answer as incorrect.